# SQL Query, or Eloquent Query a foreach loop

Tags: sql, laravel

I have a question. Say I have two collections; `CompanyOrders` and `User` and need to do a loop to fetch all users involved in company orders, how would i do that? The example of a query that i am looking for will be provided below in a foreach format.

```
$companyOrders = CompanyOrders::where('id', $company_id)->get();
$users = [];
foreach($companyOrders as $companyOrder){
  $user = User::where('id', $companyOrder['user_id'])->first();
  array_push($users, $user);
}
```

Now my next part wont work unless my $users is actually a collection. Hence the question, is there any way to query this so that `$users = User::where(filters all users who are in various different company orders and gives me all in return)->get();`

**Points to Note**

CompanyOrders has user_id, it's the link between the company_orders table and the users table.

Thanks for your time and I would really appreciated any help provided! Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: what's kind of result do u expects? just the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have built [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

In your model User:

```php
    public function companyOrders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\CompanyOrders::class);
    }
```

In your CompanyOrders Model:

```php
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);
    }
```

you can use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to find the user who has those companyOrders by `$company_id`:

```php
User::whereHas('companyOrders', function($query) use ($company_id) {
    $query->where('id', $company_id);
})
->get();
```

Comment: hmm, its similar, but it's not using $company_id. $company_id is to get all instances of CompanyOrders in this case. i need to filter it via user_id. in the table companyorders, there is a column called user_id

Comment: @UdhayanNair So did u want to get the user and their companyorders together? and the parameter is `user_id`?

Comment: yes, so basically its like this. in user table, there's the id. in companyorders, when i filter it like this; $companyOrders = CompanyOrders::where('id', $company_id)->get(); it returns a collection of items that have various different user_id's. so lets say there are 10 items in the collection, there could be 10 different user_id's. now i need to get a collection called $users from my user table that have these 10 id's. does that make sense?

Comment: @UdhayanNair so I think this is the answer, `whereHas` will use `$company` to filter the `company_orders` which has `$company_id`, and then use these collection's `user_id` to find the user...

Comment: but in my user table, i dont have $company_id, hence would the query; $query->where('id', $company_id); work? it should be fetching something like $query->where('id', $companyOrders['user_id']); right? but there are various user_id's

Comment: @UdhayanNair yes, it will work.Because I am using relationship `companyOrders`. The condition is filtered by `CompanyOrders`, not `User`.